# Update the table with the calculated field of a form in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am very new to the Acces and i am trying to calculate the Earned salary of the employee based on the no of Worked days.
For this i have created a Form to input the no of days present and calculate the earned salary based on the input.Now i want to pass this earned salary value to the table field.
Can you please help me

Comment: Take the result of whatever your calculation is and then in VBA run an update query to affect the corresponding value in the table.  `DoCmd.RunSQL` can be used in VBA to execute an SQL statement.  If you want any more help beyond that we will need more information.

Comment: I have tried writing it in After Update Event of the calculated field of the Form  but its not updating in my table.Can you pleaase correct me if i am wrong nd help me how to write it

Answer (score 1):

Firstly some house-keeping; With your field names it is best not to have any spaces in them, makes it much easier to code (from your SQL string it looks like you may have done this but just checking). Also, avoid using reserved words as field names eg don't use Name as a field name, there is a list of Visual Basic reserved words [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which will cover everything VBA and a little bit more.

Secondly, it seems you are storing a calculated field - EarnedSalary is a calculation of BasicPay, TotalWorkingDaysInMonth and ActualWorkedDays. Generally storing calculated fields is considered a no-no, ref Allen Browne's [page on calculated fields](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html). On this page Allen gives some tips on calculated fields that may help, especially if you decide you do want to store it and use Access 2010 (I'm only on 2007...).

As for your question, you still didn't tell me where your error was so it is hard to pin-point the issue. My guess is that you are calling the update Sub in the wrong place - you want to update EarnedSalary but you call the process in the AfterUpdate of that control, therefore the code won't fire until you update the field the code is meant to update. The code needs to be in the AfterUpdate of ActualWorkedDays.

Further, it looks like you are using a bound form which would mean you don't need to use the SQL update, a solution akin to Allen's example would suffice:

On the form if you have a control for each of the fields involved in the calculation:

```
Private Sub ActualWorkedDays_AfterUpdate()
     Me.EarnedSalary = Me!BasicPay / Me!TotalWorkingDays * Me!ActualWorkedDays
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite generic as you haven't given much detail but something like this in the AfterUpdate should work:

Assume controls on the form are:

txtEmpID for employee ID,
txtHourlyRate for what to multiply the number or hours by,
txtHoursWorked as what you input as hours worked

```
Dim dblEarnings as Double

dblEarnings = me!txtHourlyRate * me!HoursWorked

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [tblYourTable] (EmployeeID, EarnedSalary) VALUES (" _
    & Me!txtEmpID & "," & dblEarnings & ")",dbFailOnError
```

I would probably look to record the hours worked and the hourly rate and calculate the salary on the fly rather than storing a calculated number. Or store the hours and total and calc the hourly rate if needed.

Comment: I am very much thankful for you.I ahev tried the same to run SQL Query but its showing an unrelated object.Can you please help me .

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean when you say it is showing an unrelated object. Can you edit your answer and put you code in and tell me more on the error you are receiving?

Comment: Hello Simon Can you please me to solve this again i have tried sam eyour code is not still populating any data in table.

Comment: I need more information: What is your table called? What fields need populating? What is the calculation for your salary? What are the controls on the form called? Edit your question and paste in your code and I should be able to make some progress.

Comment: have Created an Employee table with the following fields :EMP Id ,Name,Basic Pay,Total Working Days in a month,Actual Worked Days ,Earned Salary.Now i have created Form with all the fields in the Table and am calculating the Earned Salary using Control source using Earned Salary=BasicPay/Total no of working Days in month* Actual Working Days.Now i want to populate this calculated field in the table. I will be giving the Actual Days as input on the form because this value will be changing for employees based on their Days present.So,Can you please help me out. –

Comment: Private Sub EarnedSalary_AfterUpdate()
Dim dblEarnings As Double

   dblEarnings = Me!BaicPay / Me!TotalWorkingDays * Me!ActualWorkedDays
  
    Dim strSQL As String
    
  strSQL = " UPDATE [PR] SET EarnedSalary = " & Me![dblEarnings] & ";"
  
  CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

End Sub